# In Powershell how do I get passwordLastSet as DateTime instead of as an Object from AD?

Tags: powershell, datetime, active-directory

I am trying to get the PasswordLastSet property from Active Directory as a dateTime variable, but I only know how to get it as an object. Eventually I want to compare that date with the current date to see how many days are remaining, but I can't figure out how to get it into DateTime format.

I've tried using get-aduser in different ways but I can't seem to get the date as a DateTime.

`$serviceAccount = 'serviceAccountName'
$expDate = get-aduser $serviceAccount -properties * | ft passwordlastset
$expDate.GetType()`

I would like to get a DateTime result, but I keep getting an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never pipe to a `Format-*` cmdlet and then capture the output. Those are intended for formatting output to screen. Instead use `|Select-Object -Expand passwordlastset`. What you captured is a formatting object.

```
$serviceAccount = 'serviceAccountName'
$expDate = get-aduser $serviceAccount -properties * | Select-Object -Expand passwordlastset
```

Or a shorter version would be:

```
$serviceAccount = 'serviceAccountName'
$expDate = get-aduser $serviceAccount -properties * | % passwordlastset
```

Comment: Even better would be `$expDate = (Get-ADUser $ServiceAccount -Properties *).PasswordLastSet` - and it's returned as a DateTime, as can be shown by inspecting `$expDate.GetType()`.

Comment: Um, it should be the exact same result as both of what I posted, just harder for some people to read.

Comment: Yes, but doing it your way brings in the delay of passing the ADUser object through the pipe, and invoking the `ForEach-Object`  cmdlet. Mine doesn't; it pulls the requested data directly from the ADUser object, more efficiently.

Comment: Better yet would be to only get the wanted property (besides the mandatory ones): get-aduser $serviceAccount -properties passwordlastset

Comment: @AxelAndersen - yes, but when I do that I've gotten some odd results, so I've taken to just getting the whole object.